# cakephp 2.3.0 failed to load vendor files

Tags: php, cakephp, cakephp-2.3

I am having problems loading vendor files in cakephp 2.3.0. I have tried entering `App::import('Vendor', 'EncodingProfileConfig');` just above `App::uses('AppController', 'Controller');` in my StreamsController.php file. I get the error **"class 'EncodingProfileConfig' not found"**. How do I solve this? I was using this Reference: https://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/core-utility-libraries/app.html#loading-vendor-files

The actual class is inside **app/Vendor/bitcodin/lib** directory. But after this code below failed, I tried a more straightforward approach which the above. Which failed too. What I am really trying to do is to load it without removing it in it's directory **app/Vendor/bitcodin/lib**.

```
App::build(array('Vendor' => array(APP . 'Vendor' . DS . 'bitcodin' . DS . 'lib' . DS)));
App::uses('EncodingProfileConfig', 'Vendor/bitcodin');
```

Comment: When referencing to 3rd party code, please always add references to it in your question, respectively embed an example, and show how exactly you try to use it. If people could see the contents of `EncodingProfileConfing.php`, and your try to instantiate the class, they'd see that there's more to your problem than just importing the file. Also I'd suggest that you learn about composer, and make use of it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the import by specifying the file location in parameters

```
App::import('Vendor', 'EncodingProfileConfig', array('file' => 'bitcodin' . DS . 'lib' . DS . 'EncodingProfileConfig.php' ));
// Add this line to import the class from the namespace
use bitcodin\EncodingProfileConfig;
```

Insert this code before using the class `EncodingProfileConfig` or in the begining of your file, just after  `App::uses('AppController', 'Controller');`

Comment: I put it just after `App::uses('AppController', 'Controller');` but when I try to create an object using the class, `$Obj = new EncodingProfileConfig();` I get the same error class not found error.

Comment: did you used the correct filename ? i just assumed that is `EncodingProfileConfig.php` case sensitive

Comment: **https://github.com/bitmovin/bitcodin-php/blob/8b2b15e46278759382dc9729f6752debedef6b15/lib/EncodingProfileConfig.php#L9**

Comment: I updated the answer, i just added the namespace import.

Comment: Exactly, It was a namespace problem. I discovered the same. Thanks a lot!! I voted this as the answer.

Comment: But get the message: Thanks for the feedback! Votes cast by those with less than 15 reputation are recorded, but do not change the publicly displayed post score

Answer (score 0):

Use this

App::import('Vendor', 'filename');

if your file is in some folder inside vendor then specify folder before filename like 
App::import('Vendor', 'foldername/filename');
In your case

App::import('Vendor', 'bitcodin/lib/filename');

Comment: where do I insert this? In my StreamsController.php? just before the class definition?

Comment: above conntroller calss definition

Comment: hey did you get the solution